# Как правильно завершить транзакцию в миграции knex?

Tags: javascript, mysql, миграция, knex.js

Создаю миграцию:

```
exports.up =  async function up(knex)
{
    const trx = await knex.transaction();

    try {
        await trx.raw('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders;');
        await trx.raw(`
            CREATE TABLE orders (
                ID INT(11) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                date_insert timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;`);

        await trx.commit();

    } catch (err) {
        await trx.rollback(err);
        throw err;
    }
}
```

запускаю выполнение и вижу в консоли:

```
Transaction was implicitly committed, do not mix transactions and DDL with MySQL (#805)
Batch 1 run: 1 migrations
```

т.е. вроде как миграция успешно прошла, но что я делаю не так с завершением транзакции?

Comment: *что я делаю не так с завершением транзакции?* Выполняете запрос, который вызывает принудительную фиксацию транзакции. См. [Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html). Да и какой великий смысл делать ЭТИ операции именно в транзакции? они и по одной хороши...

Comment: PS. Для Primary key поля спецификация UNIQUE избыточна.

Comment: @Akina спасибо, ознакомлюсь. а в транзакцию я эти запросы заворачиваю из-за специфики работы пакета knex, который не позволяет отправить несколько запросов в один "сырой запрос" и вызов вида return knex.raw('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders; CREATE TABLE orders...;'); падает с ошибкой. а вот с транзакциями работает

Comment: А зачем их пихать в один? делайте два отдельных обычных запроса - всё равно они именно так и выполняются.